# Find all pairs of numbers that appear in different sets

Tags: python

im new so i apologize if this is done incorrectly

i'm looking to find a way to get all the pairs (later on 3 numbers) that appear together in different sets.

Example:

```
A = (1,2,4,6,7) 
B = (1,4,5,8) 
C = (1,2,8)
```

i need to get a result where:

- 1,2 appear in A and C
- 1,4 Appear in A and B
- 1,8 appear in B and C

I tried running through every set , creating pairs on all of them and then comparing but i am not sure that is the correct (and efficient way)

I am looking for the the correct way to implement it in python (the proper way if you will)

Comment: You can intersect each pair of sets: the intersection has all the common elements: you'd just need to extract pairs from those intersections.

Comment: you are working on `tuples`. if you used [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set)s you could just [intersect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) them.

Comment: You can find the intersection of two tuples turning them into sets and then applying the ```&``` operator: ```intersec=set(A)&set(B)```

Comment: The pairs to extract from the intersections are combinations and "itertools" module provides a handy function for this.

Comment: What if `C` also contains `7`: do you get extra pairs like 1,7 for `A` & `C` (next to 1, 8), or a "triplet" 1,7,8 for `A` &  `C`? And what if `8` is removed from `C`: should the single value `1` between `A` & `C` be ignored?

Comment: what should this result look like in your example above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the intersection method of set in python like this :

```
In [1]: A = {1, 2, 4, 6, 7}

In [2]: C = {1, 2, 8}

In [3]: A.intersection(C)
Out[3]: {1, 2}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this out:

```
from itertools import combinations

A = (1,2,4,6,7) 
B = (1,4,5,8) 
C = (1,2,8)


def get_pairs(sets):
    return [set.intersection(set(X), set(Y)) for X, Y in combinations(sets,2)]

print(get_pairs([A, B, C]))
```

You have something much modular.

return:

```
[{1, 4}, {1, 2}, {8, 1}]
```

If you want it in one-line it gives:

```
import itertools
print([set.intersection(set(X), set(Y)) for X, Y in itertools.combinations([(1,2,4,6,7), (1,4,5,8) , (1,2,8)],2)])
```

Comment: yes , this is what i was looking for , thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can find by using  "set.intersection" in Python. For Example-

```
A={1,2,4,6,7}
B={1,4,5,8} 
C={1,2,8}
a=set.intersection(A,C)
b=set.intersection(A,B)
c=set.intersection(B,C)
print("The common in set A&C:",a)
print("The common in set A&B:",b)
print("The common in set B&C:",c)
```